# Retrieve location of VNET through Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to pull the VNET location using just the azurerm_virtual_network data resource.  Terraform's documentation says teh location attribute is available, but it is not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                 = "my-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "my-vnet-resource-group"
}

output "LOCATION" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.location}"
}
```

This is the error message I am receiving..

```
output.LOCATION: Resource 'data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet' 
does not have attribute 'location' for variable 
'data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.location'
```

Any help getting around this is sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So doesn't seem there is a way to do it through the azurerm_virtual_network data resource.  However, I was able to get it working by using the azurerm_resource_group data resource in conjunction with azurerm_virtual_network.

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                 = "my-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "my-vnet-resource-group"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name}"
}

output "LOCATION" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/virtual_network.html#attributes-reference) it is not possible. honestly, terraform is just bad ;)

Comment: Interesting... this page says you can.. [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_network.html)

Comment: this is not a data block, this is resource block, which wont work for you obviously. also, your solution is naive, in a sense that vnet can be in a different region to the resource group, so... I suggest you upvote my answer at least, because this is how terraform works